# No se imprimen bien las listas doblemente enlazadas

Tags: c++, estructuras-de-datos

estoy estudiando estructura de datos en c++, pero llegue al momento en donde no se esta imprimiendo de forma correcta mi lista, en la primera opcion, que es "Insertar()" se imprime solo el primer elemento de mi lista, y en la segunda opcion que es "Fina()" solo se imprime correctamente hasta el tercer elemento.

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda si me pudieran orientar para encontrar mi error.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct Nodo
{
    int dato;
    Nodo *sig;
    Nodo *ant;
};

typedef struct Nodo *Tlista;
typedef struct Nodo *pNodo;

Tlista lista = NULL;

void Imprimir(Tlista);
void Insertar(Tlista &);
void Final(Tlista &);

int main()
{
    int opc;
    while(1)
    {
        cout << "L I S T A S  D O B L E S" << endl
             << "1) Insertar al incio" << endl
             << "2) Insertar al final" << endl
             << "10) Salir" << endl
             << "Seleccione Opcion: ";
        do
        {
            cin >> opc;
        }while(opc < 1 && opc > 10);

        switch(opc)
        {
        case 1:
            Insertar(lista);
        break;

        case 2:
            Final(lista);
        break;

        case 10:
            exit(0);
        break;

        default:
            cout << "Opcion Invalida" << endl;
            system("pause");
            system("cls");
        break;
        }
    }
}

void Imprimir(Tlista lista)
{
    pNodo q = lista;

    while(q != NULL)
    {
        cout << q -> dato << " ";
        q = q -> sig;
    }

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    system("cls");
}

void Insertar(Tlista &lista)
{
    pNodo q = new struct Nodo ;
    int x;

    cout << "Introduce el dato: ";
        cin >> x;

    q -> dato = x;

    if(lista == NULL)
    {
        lista = q;
        q -> sig = NULL;
        q -> ant = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        q -> sig = lista;
        q -> ant = lista -> ant;
        lista -> ant = q;
    }

    Imprimir(lista);
}

void Final(Tlista &lista)
{
    pNodo q = new struct Nodo ;
    int x;

    cout << "Introduce el dato: ";
        cin >> x;

    q -> dato = x;

    if(lista == NULL)
    {
        lista = q;
        q -> sig = NULL;
        q -> ant = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        q -> sig = lista -> sig;
        lista -> sig = q;
        q -> ant = lista;
    }

    Imprimir(lista);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas realizando mal el llenado de la lista, aplica estas correciones rapidas que hice:

*para ambos casos se declara temp de esta forma*

```
pNodo temp = new struct Nodo ;
```

-Para el metodo Insertar esto:

```
if(lista == NULL)
{
  lista = q;
  q -> sig = NULL;
  q -> ant = NULL;
}
else
{
  temp = q;
  q = lista;
  lista = temp;
  lista -> sig = q;
  lista -> ant = NULL;
}
```

-Para el metodo Final esto:

```
    if(lista == NULL)
    {
        q -> sig = NULL;
        q -> ant = NULL;
        lista = q;

    }
    else
    {
        temp=lista;
        while(temp -> sig != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp -> sig;
        }
        q -> sig = NULL;
        q -> ant = temp;
        temp -> sig = q;
    }
```

Eso es todo, lo que pasaba era que asignabas los datos siempre a "lista" por eso solo contabas con 3 numeros como maximo en la lista enlazada.

Answer (score 4):

A parte de las correcciones mencionadas por [eferion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/111507/2742), hay otras cosas que debes tener en cuenta.

#### En C++, `struct` no forma parte del tipo.

En el lenguaje C, es necesario anteponer `struct` antes del nombre de una estructura, porque `struct` forma parte del tipo de datos, pero en C++ esto no es así, por lo tanto puedes cambiar tus alias a:

```
typedef Nodo *Tlista; // Sin anteponer 'struct'.
typedef Nodo *pNodo;  // Sin anteponer 'struct'.
```

Aunque yo, personalmente prefiero esta notación:

```
using Tlista = Nodo *;
using pNodo = Nodo *;
```

#### Confundes nodos con listas.

¿De verdad no te parece raro que el alias de lista y el alias de nodo **sean iguales**? Estás definiendo que una lista (`Tlista`) es un puntero a nodo y un puntero a nodo (`pNodo`) es un puntero a nodo.

En otras palabras: estás diciendo que un escalón es una escalera, o que una escalera y un escalón son intercambiables... lo cuál no tiene sentido.

#### Crea un objeto Lista.

Para evitar el problema del punto anterior, crea un objeto `Lista` en el que añadir los métodos que ahora mismo has dejado sueltos:

```
struct Lista
{
    void Imprimir() const;
    void Insertar();
    void Final();

private:
    struct Nodo
    {
        int dato;
        Nodo *sig = nullptr;
        Nodo *ant = nullptr;
    };

    Nodo *raiz = nullptr;
};
```

Si te fijas, los métodos no reciben de parámetro un nodo, ya que los nodos con los que la lista va a trabajar ya están contenidos en el propio objeto (`Lista::raiz`). También estoy usando el literal de puntero nulo (`nullptr`) ya que es más adecuado y seguro que la macro `NULL` y el nodo es un objeto anidado dentro de la lista ya que no hay necesidad de exponerlo fuera de la lista.

#### `Insertar` y `Final`.

No me queda claro que hacen esas funciones, creo que son para hacer crecer la lista por la derecha (alargando `Nodo::sig`) o por la izquierda (alargando `Nodo::ant`), veamos tus algoritmos:

En `Insertar`.

Enlazas todos los nodos al nodo inicial, con lo cuál nunca creas una lista.

```
q -> sig = lista;
q -> ant = lista -> ant;
lista -> ant = q;
```

Tras insertar tres datos, tu estructura en memoria tiene este aspecto:
[image]

El siguiente de cada nodo que insertas apunta siempre al nodo inicial, si fuese una lista cada nodo estará enlazado una sola vez. Por otro lado se ve claramente por qué al imprimir sólo se imprime el nodo inicial: porque el siguiente del nodo inicial siempre es nulo.

En `Final`.

También enlazas con el nodo inicial, pero de una manera más rara:

```
    q -> sig = lista -> sig;
    lista -> sig = q;
    q -> ant = lista;
```

Tras insertar tres datos, tu estructura en memoria tiene este aspecto:
[image]

Por lo tanto insertando desde el los datos no te conservan el orden de inserción porque no enlazas correctamente.

#### Conclusión

Debes revisar tus algoritmos de inserción. Te aconsejo dibujar unos esquemas como los que pongo de ejemplo para ver qué estás haciendo.

Answer (score 2):

C++ no es C. En C++ las estructuras de datos (comúnmente llamadas clases, aunque uses `struct`) difieren de las que has visto al aprender C en que disponen, entre otras cosas, de constructores (funciones que permiten inicializar las estructuras de datos de forma automática).

Lo normal al crear un objeto es que sus punteros se inicialicen automáticamente para evitar *despistes*:

```
struct Nodo
{
    int dato;
    Nodo *sig;
    Nodo *ant;

  // Constructor por defecto
  Nodo()
    : sig(nullptr), ant(nullptr) // C++11 en adelante
    : sig(NULL), ant(NULL)       // C++03 y anteriores
  { }

  // Constructor para asignar el dato
  Nodo(int dato)
    : dato(dato), sig(nullptr), ant(nullptr)
  { }
};
```

Por otro lado, en C++ no es necesario usar `struct` cada dos por tres... el lenguaje es, en ese aspecto, un pelín más legible que C:

```
// sintaxis C
typedef struct Nodo *Tlista;
pNodo temp = new struct Nodo; // nota que en C habría que usar malloc

// sintaxis C++
typedef Nodo* TLista;
pNodo temp = new Nodo;    // Se invoca el constructor por defecto
pNodo temp = new Nodo(5); // Se invoca el segundo constructor
```

Bien, si echamos un vistazo a la función `Insertar`:

```
void Insertar(Tlista &lista)
{
    pNodo q = new struct Nodo ;
    int x;

    cout << "Introduce el dato: ";
    cin >> x;

    q -> dato = x;

    if(lista == NULL)
    {
        lista = q;
        q -> sig = NULL;
        q -> ant = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        q -> sig = lista;
        q -> ant = lista -> ant;
        lista -> ant = q;
    }

    Imprimir(lista);
}
```

vemos que el `else` hace algo raro: Añades un elemento anterior a `lista` y luego imprimes a partir de `lista`... estás ignorando el elemento que acabas de añadir. Asumiendo que has implementado el constructor por defecto el código debería quedar más bien así:

```
void Insertar(Tlista &lista)
{
    pNodo q = new Nodo;

    cout << "Introduce el dato: ";
        cin >> q->dato;

    if(lista != NULL)
    {
        q->sig = lista;
        lista->ant = q;
    }

    lista = q;

    Imprimir(lista);
}
```

Nota que el puntero `lista` **siempre** se actualiza. Es necesario ya que se supone que **siempre** se van a añadir los nodos al principio de la lista.

Por otro lado la función `Final` también tiene sus problemillas:

```
else
{
    q -> sig = lista -> sig;
    lista -> sig = q;
    q -> ant = lista;
}
```

Aquí el código está añadiendo el nuevo nodo en la segunda posición, no en la última. Además no lo hace del todo bien ya que el que pasa a ser el tercer nodo tiene como `ant` al nodo `lista` (no lo has actualizado).

Lo que tienes que hacer es localizar el último nodo de la lista y añadir el nuevo nodo detrás del mismo. Esto se consigue facilmente con un `while`:

```
    Nodo* ultimo = lista;
    while( ultimo->sig ) ultimo = ultimo->sig;
```

Es decir, el último nodo será aquel que no tiene más nodos detrás de él.

Una vez localizado este nodo únicamente será necesario (si se ha implementado el constructor por defecto) actualizar dos punteros.

```
else
{
    Nodo* ultimo = lista;
    while( ultimo->sig ) ultimo = ultimo->sig;

    ultimo->sig = q;
    q->ant = ultimo;
}
```

Por cierto, no olvides liberar la memoria antes de salir del programa... no hay que perder las buenas costumbres:

```
while( lista )
{
  Nodo* temp = lista;
  lista = lista->sig;
  delete temp;
}
```

Ah sí, por compatibilidad, para importar `cin` y `cout` te sugiero usar:

```
#include <iostream>
```

En vez de

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
```

La primera viene contemplada como librería estándar (a diferencia de la segunda). Te ahorrarás toda una fuente de errores al probar el código en otros sistemas (como el pc de clase a la hora de enseñar tu ejercicio, por ejemplo)